# executing python command remotely

Tags: python, ssh

How can I run the `os.dirlist()` python command on remote host, using ssh connection?

Tried to run `ls <path>` over `ssh`, but the returned result could not be used to extract information.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve on the remote server? If you need file transfers, perhaps you should use `sftp` instead. For a Python-controllable SSH session (and `sftp` client), look at https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh <remote_host> 'python -c "<statement>"'
```

Example:

```
ssh localhost 'python -c "import os; print os.getcwd()"'
```